# UIColor expected a type after update to xCode 7.3

Tags: objective-c, uicolor, xcode7.3

My project stop to compile after was updated to 7.3 version. For this moment main problem is in header files when I want to return `UIColor`. xCode tells me `Expected a type` error. Is there some way to handle with this situation?

**Edit:** my code (nothing special)

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface NSString (Color)

- (UIColor *)rgbColor; //Expected a type
- (UIColor *)hexColor; //Expected a type

@end
```

Answer (score 3):

You should import [uikit](/questions/tagged/uikit) if you are using UIColor.

Comment: In theory yes. But why it was not need before 7.3?

Comment: I don't have idea about that. Check that your method is not get called before it's defined.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
@class UIColor;
```

above `@interface`.

It'll fix the `expected a type` error.